# Como aplicar uma função para vários objetos? (Javascript Puro)

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Por exemplo, tenho uma `div` dentro de uma variável `obj`

```
 obj = document.getElementById("objeto");
```

..Quero que uma função seja aplicada a ela, dessa forma

```
 window.onload = function(){
    window.onclick = function (){
       obj = document.getElemntById("obj");
       obj.ver();
    }
    function ver(){
       this.style.backgroundColor = "#333333";
    }
 }
```

Como poderia fazer para essa aplicação funcionar?

O meu código completo, abixo:

```
    <script>        
    HTMLElement.prototype.mover = function(){

        movendo = false;
        valor = 0;
        calc = 0;
        resto = 0;
        this.onmousedown = function(e){                
            movendo = true;
            valor = e.pageX + document.body.scrollLeft;     
            calc = valor - this.offsetLeft;
            resto = this.offsetWidth - calc;

            valor2 = e.pageY + document.body.scrollTop;     
            calc2 = valor2 - this.offsetTop;
            resto2 = this.offsetHeight - calc2;

            this.style.cursor = "move";

        };            
        window.onmouseup = function(){

            movendo = false;
            this.style.cursor = "pointer";        
        };

       window.onmousemove = function(e){
            if( movendo == true ) {

                this.style.left = (e.pageX + document.body.scrollLeft) - this.offsetWidth + resto + "px";
                this.style.top = (e.pageY + document.body.scrollTop) - this.offsetHeight + resto2 + "px";

            }
        };
    }

    window.onload = function(){            
        obj = document.getElementById("obj");
        obj.mover();            
    }         
    </script>
```

Comment: Este site explica como fazer várias coisas sem o uso do jQuery. Talvez te seja útil: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Andrey, Obrigado, sim vai me ajudar!

Comment: @SamirBraga, deixei um comentário em baixo, aqui fica uma versão no jsFiddle também: http://jsfiddle.net/M238g/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer isso tem de extender o `prototype` e adicionar esse método aos elementos.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/xYfMa/

```
HTMLElement.prototype.ver = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#333333";
}

window.onload = function () {
    window.onclick = function () {
        obj = document.getElementById("obj");
        obj.ver();
    }
}
```

Usando a palavra `prototype` acede-se ao protótipo de todos os elementos e esse método fica disponivel em todos os elementos. Cuidado somente para não escrever por cima de métodos já existentes, pois esta ferramenta é bem poderosa.

Comment: Funciona, mas não no meu arquivo, eu vou editar a resposta, e vou coloca o código completo, você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @SamirBraga, faça uma demo do problema no jsfiddle e coloque aqui que eu dou uma olhada.

Comment: Está aqui http://codepen.io/SamirChaves/pen/gFwpc

Comment: Exemplo funcionando sem a utilização do prototype
http://codepen.io/SamirChaves/pen/KHpyi

Comment: ótimo exemplo do prototype. +1

Comment: @SamirBraga, as funções que não usam prototype não podem usar o `this` da mesma maneira que com prototype. Mas pode usar assim `var este = e.target` como fiz neste exemplo: http://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/JkGrA

Comment: Obrigado, você me ajudou muito!!